# evaluateJavaScript swift nil

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview

Please tell me, I'm trying to take input value from webview.
Why do I get "nil".
What could be the problem?
Screen provided below

[image]
Code provided below

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    WebView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
  }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
  func makeUIView(context: Context) - > WKWebView {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    return webView
  }


  func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    let liveView = "https://**/"
    if let url = URL(string: liveView) {
      let request = URLRequest(url: url)
      webView.load(request)
      webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('ses').value") {
        (result, error) in
        print(result)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK `getElementsByName` returns array which doesnt have `value` as property. try `document.getElementsByName('ses')[0].value` to get the value of first element or loop through those to get values of all elements

Comment: @Cerlin Sorry there should be `getElementsById`

Comment: There is no method as `getElementsById`. You can get only one element with id so the method name is `getElementById` (singular)

Comment: @Cerlin Yes, I know, but the answer is still `nil`

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait until the page loads.

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5.0, repeats: true) {
  (timer) in
  webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('ses').value") {
    (result, error) in
    print(result!)
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't need that. Usually you should call ```evaluateJavascript``` in a method called ```didFinish``` (or something similar). This is why you declare a completion handler in your ```{ }``` brackets. The completion handler will be called when the page is loaded and javascript evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if webView is completely loaded.

To check if webView is loaded:

```swift
class ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate{

    let webView = WKWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        
        let myURL = URL(string:"https://someWebSite.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
        
        
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Loaded")
    }
}
```

for more info about [navigationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate)

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you don't have this element in your document.

```js
// element exists
console.log(document.getElementById('demo').value)

// element doesn't exist
console.log(document.getElementById('foo'))
```

```html
<div id="demo" value="demo-value">Demo</div>
```

Comment: This item is on the page!